# htaccess mod_rewrite internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

So I'm trying to clean up my URLs ready for my sites public release, this is how current URLs look like:
http://pattersoncode.ca/index.php?a=help

But I'm trying to turn that into
http://pattersoncode.ca/help

I used a mod_rewrite generator online, and it gave me this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

But that gives me an Internal Server Error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules are looping, since `^([^/]*)$` will match `index.php` (or a blank URI). The rewrite engine will keep applying all the rules until the URI stops changing. You can add some conditions to prevent this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

But are you sure mod_rewrite is loaded? If you put these tags around the rewrite stuff:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

</IfModule>
```

Are you still getting the 500 server error? If not, then you need to make sure you're loading mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file, and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

It rewrites any URL except a real file or directory to `index.php?a=xyz`.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your `.htaccess`? I know that code to work, because it's straight out of a live website.